# How to expand all parent node of particular child node using nested tree control of mat tree in angular 8?

Tags: angular, tree, treeview, material-ui, mat

`getBookOutlineBar` method will take a list of nodes and the selected node which needs to be selected when sidebar of outline opens.
I have implemented expand method to expand all parent node but it is only expanding one particular node, not all parent nodes.

If page "Heading" is opened and I click on outline sidebar than all parent nodes should be expanded and heading should be selected.
I have used nested tree control of mat tree in angular 8: see [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dklgxbrynad?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts)

```js
getBookOutlineBar() {
  let customURL = '';
  this.bookService.GetBookOutlineBar(this.bookId, location.hash).subscribe(data => {
    this.dataSource.data = data.list;
    if (data.selectedNode != null) {
      this.selectedNode = data.selectedNode;
      this.treeControl.collapseAll();
      this.expand(this.dataSource.data, this.selectedNode.UniqueId);
    }
  })
}
expand(data: BookOutlineBar[], uniqueId: string): any {
  data.forEach(node => {
    if (node.Children && node.Children.find(c => c.UniqueId === uniqueId)) {
      this.treeControl.expand(node);
      this.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes, node.UniqueId);
    }
    else if (node.Children && node.Children.find(c => c.Children)) {
      this.expand(node.Children, uniqueId);
    }
  });
}
```

I want to expand all parent nodes of selected node like in this image:

[image: Desired state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
 if (node.Children && node.Children.find(c => c.UniqueId === uniqueId)) {
            this.treeControl.expand(node);
            this.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes, node.UniqueId);
          }
```

Replace with

```
 if (node.Children && node.Children.find(c => c.UniqueId === uniqueId)) {
            this.treeControl.expand(node);
            this.expand(this.dataSource.data, node.UniqueId);
          }
```

Comment: I would like to comment on this implementation. I can confirm that this code works. Unfortunately, this method does not work with a nested node design that contains a lot of data. You can then see a max call stack size error in the console log of the web browser. Now I don't use a nested node design but a flat node design and use the method mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324524/get-parent-hierarchy-from-a-child-node-in-angular-6-material-tree

Answer (score 0):

-- Init treeControl with datasource data

```
private setDatasource() {
   this.treeControl.dataNodes = this.dataSource.data;
}
```

-- Algorithm to expand to selected node (ex in this code: 'this.selectedFleet')

```
  // Starting from a list of node
  private expandTreeToSelectedNode() {
    for (const dataNode of this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
      this.expandTreeToSelectedNodeRec(dataNode);
    }
  }

  // Starting from one node
  private expandTreeToSelectedNodeRec(current: Node): boolean {
    if (current.items.length === 0 && current.id === this.selectedFleet.id) {
      this.treeControl.expand(current);
      return true;
    }
    for (const child of current.items) {
      if (this.expandTreeToSelectedNodeRec(child)) {
        this.treeControl.expand(current);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```